# Django: ListView. Where can I declare variables that I want to have on template?

Tags: python, django, listview, templates

One of my tables in my app is called `Gallery` and I have the following class to list all of the objects on that table:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from galleries.models import Gallery 

class GalleryList(ListView):
 template_name = "path/to/template"
 context_object_name = "object_list"

 def queryset(self):
  return Gallery.objects.order_by('-title')[:20]
```

And it does the job. On my template I do the following:

```
{% block gallery_list %}
    <h1>Gallery List</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for gallery in object_list %}
            <li><img src="{{ gallery.thumbnail.url }}" />{{ gallery.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything works as expected. The thing here is that on my `base.html` template I have `{% block title %}` for the `meta title` tag, `{% block description %}` for my `meta description` tag in the header. And I want to be able to declare it somewhere and pass it to the view. To be clear, the variables `title` and `description` are strings (ex: `title="List of all galleries on website"`).

On the view I want to do something like:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}
{% block description %}{{ description|default:title }}{% endblock %}
```

But, on the class `GalleryList` I don't know where to declare the variables `title` and `description`. I don't know if that's possible or proper for Django. I want to do what's right.

Also, as I have a costume template for listing all the galleries I could just do:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}List of all galleries on website{% endblock %}
{% block description %}List of all galleries on website...{% endblock %}
```

But then again, I don't know if that's proper for a well coded Django app. I'm a beginner with Django and I would like to know what's the way to go about this. Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: This question is too broad but you can read http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the `ListView`s [`get_context_data` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data) to add whatever additional context variables to you want to the context:

```
class GalleryList(ListView):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(GalleryList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = 'My Title'
        ctx['description'] = 'My Description'
        return ctx
```

The other approach - of having a template that fills in this information - is also sound. Which is better really depends on how dynamic the data is. If the title/description is based on model data or some other factors, then it makes sense to set it in the view. If it is fixed for a particular template then it is probably cleaner to put in in a template that extends `base.html`.

Comment: `title` and `description` are actually fixed so I would stick with the template option. Thanks for the quick answer. :-)